# URL redirect to GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In a PHP website I want to set a redirect if there are variables in the URL inside a specific folder (.com/promo/).

When a user visits:

```
www.example.com/promo/Marco-Aurelio
```

Redirect to:

```
www.example.com/promo/?user=Marco-Aurelio
```

What PHP code or htaccess rules would you use?

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htaccess` in the apache DirectoryRoot containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/promo/(?![?])(.+)
RewriteRule ^ /promo/?user=%1 [L]
```

So that the url

`http://www.example.com/promo/Marco-Aurelio`

Will be redirected to

`http://www.example.com/promo/?user=Marco-Aurelio`

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: add `RewriteEngine on` line at the beginning

Comment: do you have the apache module `mod_rewrite` installed ?

Comment: Realized that it was causing infinite redirections, so error 500. This is solved now. Check above.

Answer (score 0):

```
function RedirectToFolder(){

    //lets get the uri
    $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    //remove slashes from beginning and ending
    $uri = trim($uri,"/");

   //lets check if the uri pattern matches the uri or not
   //if it doesnt match dont continue
   if(!preg_match("/promo\/(.+)/i,$uri)){
       return false;
   }

   //lets now get the last part of the uri
    $explodeUri = explode("/",$uri);

    $folderName = end($explodeUri);

    //lets get the new url 
    $redirectUrl = "http://www.example.com/promo/?user=$folderName";

    Header('Location:'.$redirectUrl);
    exit();
    }//end function
```

So just call the function after the php opening tag

```
RedirectToFolder();
```